# Bad sdcard report 32DB but has only 2GB wired in, how to detect valid area

Tags: linux, bad-sectors, bad-blocks

I bought a while ago a sdcard that is supposedly 32GB, but after using it for some time, I found that it only has 2GB wired in. If I write past the 2GB limit, the files I read are composed of zero bytes.

I know the first 2GB are valid, but I don't know exactly at which sector the valid area stops. Do you know how on Linux I could easily find the last usable sector. So I could create a filesystem that is limited to this valid area

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally recommend throwing it out. You've got a card that seems to be deliberately mis-reporting it's capabilities (presumably in order to get you to pay for memory you weren't getting). There's no good way for you to know just how it's going to behave, even if you limit the filesystem size to the 'actual' flash area - It may be doing all sorts of odd tricks like keeping the most recent 2 GB of data or whatever in order to better fool the potential customer.

I don't think you can trust this device, no matter what you do to it - even if you get it 'working' as a 2 GB device, it may still be a really crummy one and die early.

Comment: Oh god, and it's so easy to do this, too. I could have a MicroSD report that it hold 2TB, if I really wanted. Actually, I think I will, just to see if my theory is right.

Comment: The drive stopped functioning anyway

Answer (score 1):

There are many fake flash drives 'doing the rounds' recently... [here](http://sosfakeflash.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/h2testw-14-gold-standard-in-detecting-usb-counterfeit-drives/) is a good piece of software for testing. [here](http://flashchiptech.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/the-difference-between-a-fake-usb-memory-pen-stick-and-a-substandard-one/) is another good read :)

Comment: Th the page you link, there is a program for linux: https://fixfakeflash.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/linux-h2testw-alternative-program-called-f3-by-michel%c2%a0machado/